# Grouped letters

Tags: knowledge, pattern

Each of the following sets has something in common; that is, the members of each set are related to one another in the same way.

- D, E, and G
- K and Y
- I and O
- N and P
- U, V, and W
- A and R

What trait do they share, and what letter goes with J?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looking at this

> up-to-date list of 118 chemical element symbols ordered alphabetically
>  [image: Alphabetical-List-of-Element-Symbols]

We see D, E, and G have

> Three symbols (all two-letters)  starting with these letters
>  Db Dubnium, Ds Darmstadtium, Dy Dysprosium
>  Er Erbium, Es Einsteinium, Eu Europium
>  Ga Gallium, Gd Gadolinium, Ge Germanium

and similarly, K and Y

> Two symbols (one each of one-letter and two-letters)
>  K Potassium, Kr Krypton
>  Y Yttrium, Yb Ytterbium

I and O

> Three symbols  (one one-letter and two two-letters)
>  I Iodine, In Indium, Ir Iridium
>  O Oxygen, Og Oganesson , Os Osmium

N and P

> Nine symbols (one one-letter and eight two-letters)
>   N Nitrogen, Na Sodium, Nb Niobium, Nd Neodymium, Ne Neon, Nh Nihonium, Ni Nickel, No Nobelium, Np Neptunium
>  P Phosphorus, Pa Protactinium, Pb Lead, Pd Palladium, Pm Promethium, Po Polonium, Pr Praseodymium, Pt Platinum, Pu Plutonium

U, V, and W

> One symbol (all one-letter)
>  U Uranium
>  V Vanadium
>  W Tungsten

A and R

> Eight symbols (all two-letters)
>  Ac Actinium, Ag Silver, Al Aluminum, Am Americium, Ar Argon, As Arsenic, At Astatine, Au Gold
>  Ra Radium, Rb Rubidium, Re Rhenium, Rf Rutherfordium, Rg Roentgenium, Rh Rhodium, Rn Radon, Ru Ruthenium

What letter goes with J?

> Q as there is no chemical symbol starting with this letter (J and Q are not even in the name of any chemical element or symbol)